# dummy variables and joining data frames using a for loop in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, dummy-variable

I am trying to do get dummy variables and do some data cleaning in two separate data frames using a for loop but it does not work, it compiles but nothing happens to my data frames

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYgsD.png)

then I run this

```
data_cleanBase = [dataABase, dataTestBase]
for dataset in data_cleanBase: 
    dataset = dataset.join(pd.get_dummies(dataset['Embarked'])).join(pd.get_dummies(dataset['Sex']))
```

and again I get

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tQAe.png)

Nothing happens in the my data sets

Comment: You are assigning the result to the loop iterator `dataset`, but this does not update the variables in the list `data_cleanBase`. Try saving the transformed DataFrames into a new list. Something like `res = []` before the `for` loop, then `res.append(dataset.join(...))` in the for loop.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and your expected output? `pd.get_dummies` should be able to do this in a single call, you just need to be smart about the arguments.

Comment: @ALollz my out put is data sets in the data_CleanBase [] with dummy variables, I know I can do this individually for each data set but I want to use loop to be more efficient

Answer (score 0):

To replace the elements of a list while iterating over the list, you need to reference the elements of the list using their indices.

So, if you want to modify the list in place:

```
data_cleanBase = [dataABase, dataTestBase]
for i, dataset in enumerate(data_cleanBase): 
    data_cleanBase[i] = dataset.join(pd.get_dummies(dataset['Embarked'])).join(pd.get_dummies(dataset['Sex']))
```

Otherwise, you can put the results in a new list:

```
data_cleanBase = [dataABase, dataTestBase]
augmented_data = []
for dataset in data_cleanBase:
    augmented_data.append(dataset.join(pd.get_dummies(dataset['Embarked'])).join(pd.get_dummies(dataset['Sex'])))
```

Comment: I used this, if I put dataABase.head() and print the dataABase it wont have any dummy variables. but if I put data_cleanBase[1].head() it shows that it has dummy variables, whats the difference ?! isn't it the same ?!

Comment: @ShahinTaghikhani - `data_cleanBase` holds a reference to a `Dataframe` object. Doing `data_cleanBase[i] = x` replaces that reference with a new reference to a new object. `dataABase` hasn't changed; `data_cleanBase` just no longer has a reference to it. Some pandas operations have options to be done `inplace`, but `join()` is not one of them. It always creates a new Dataframe and leave the original two dataframes unchanged. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html.